# Error occurring while executing SoapUI test in command line

Tags: soap, command-line, cmd, soapui

I am executing SoapUI (5.2.1) tests via command line successfully.

However I am always getting this error during execution. The error appears in every single test but they always pass with success.

Any clue what is happening? Some wrong configuration of the project?

**Error:**

```
18:44:17,301 ERROR [EvalPropertyResolver] Error evaluating script
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testStep for class: 
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase
Possible solutions: testSteps, testSuite
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.EvalPropertyResolver.doEval(EvalPropertyResolver.java:164)
    at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.resolvers.EvalPropertyResolver.resolveProperty(EvalPropertyResolver.java:144)
    at com.eviware.soapui.model.propertyexpansion.PropertyExpander.expand(PropertyExpander.java:190) ...
...
```

**EDIT:** based on the comments

One of the request has following statement and it is working from SoapUI, but not when run from testrunner.

```
<id>${=modelItem.testStep.name}</id>
```

Comment: Please show your respective script for review.

Comment: I do not have any. I am reusing simple tests implemented by someone but I am not able to find any scripts. Where they can be stored or implemented?

Comment: Sure? Because error is coming from `Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)`

Comment: @Rao I searched and I found this in test XML `<id>${=modelItem.testStep.name}</id>`. When executing in SoapUI this works fine. Via command line this is replaced by `<id>No such property: testStep for class: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase
Possible solutions: testSteps, testSuite</id>`. Any clue?

Comment: koxta, please check the answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below change.
**Change from:**

```
<id>${=modelItem.testStep.name}</id>
```

**To:**

```
<id>${= context.currentStep.name}</id>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks, and also thanks for the question edit.

Comment: @koxta, glad that it helped.